# The function always returns null, I am stuck on it

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit

I am fetching images from a `REST API` and assigning them to an Array successfully on onResponse. However, I am unable to pass a random image to another class due to it always returns `empty`.
How do I make it? Please help me.

My `function` as follows:

```
private String[] headerImages = new String[10];

public String fetchOnlyImages(String url) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                    String credential = Credentials.basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header(AUTH, credential).build();
                }
            }).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NewsService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    final NewsService newsService = retrofit.create(NewsService.class);
    Call<HolderNode> holderNodeCall = newsService.holderNode(url);



    holderNodeCall.enqueue(new Callback<HolderNode>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HolderNode> call, retrofit2.Response<HolderNode> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                HolderNode holderNode = response.body();
                MainNode mainNode;

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < holderNode.nodes.size(); i++) {
                        mainNode = holderNode.nodes.get(i);
                        if (mainNode.node.image != null) {
                            String imageUrl = mainNode.node.image.src.substring(0, mainNode.node.image.src.length() - 13);
                            headerImages[i] = imageUrl;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HolderNode> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    Random random = new Random();
    int chosenNumber = random.nextInt(headerImages.length);

    return headerImages[chosenNumber];
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't return from this method - that's not how async code works.

You must continue your processing from within the `onResponse` method, after you are guaranteed to have an array.

Your issue is that the null array is returned before the onResponse is ever entered

---

You can provide a parameter for a callback into `fetchOnlyImages`, and pass that through to the network call